# Unmatched ) in reg when using lc function

Tags: perl, lowercase

I am trying to run the following code:

```
$lines = "Enjoyable )) DAY";
$lines =~ lc $lines;
print $lines;
```

It fails on the second line where I get the error mentioned in the title. I understand the brackets are causing the trouble. I think I could use "quotemeta", but the thing is that my string contains info that I go on to process later, so I would like to keep the string intact as far as possible and not tamper with it too much.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The statement `$lines =~ lc $lines` doesn't really make any sense. Did you mean to write `$lines = lc $lines` ?

Comment: yes, that was indeed what I meant to write...thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems here.

**1. `=~` is used to execute a specific set of operations**

The `=~` operator is used to either match with `//`, `m//`, `qr//` or a string; or to substitute with `s///` or `tr///`.

If all you want to do is lowercase the contents of `$lines` then you should use `=` not `=~`.

```
$lines = "Enjoyable )) DAY";
$lines = lc $lines;
print $lines;
```

**2. Regular expressions have special characters which must be escaped**

If you want to match `$lines` against a lower case version of `$Lines`, which should return true if `$lines` was already entirely lower case and false otherwise, then you need to escape the ")" characters.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $lines = "enjoyable )) day";

if ($lines =~ lc quotemeta $lines) {
    print "lines is lower case\n";
}

print $lines;
```

Note this is a toy example trying to find a reason for doing `$lines =~ lc $lines` - It would be much better (faster, safer) to solve this with `eq` as in `$lines eq lc $lines`.

See `perldoc -f quotemeta` or http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html for more details on quotemeta.

Comment: (1) is wrong. `=~` is used to specify an argument for the `m`, `s` and `tr` operators, none of which are regex, and one of which has nothing to do with regex. The operator that does create regex doesn't even use `=~`.

Comment: Good point, I'll clarify my wording. I'm not sure about your "the operator that does create regex..." point though - if you had a regular expression object created with `qr//` you would use `=~` to match against it, right?

Answer (score 0):

=~ is used for regular expressions. "lc" is not part of regex, it's a function like this: $new = lc($old);

I don't recall the regex operator for lowercase, because I use lc() all the time.

Comment: `=~` is used to specify an argument for the `m`, `s` and `tr` operators, none of which are regex, and one of which has nothing to do with regex. The operator that does create regex doesn't even use `=~`.